# Android - Webview - rotate image and scale to fit page width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

To display an image I chose to use the Webview component because it allows easy interactive scaling.

How can I first rotate the image 90 and then scale the result to fit the full width of the webview / screen?

This is what I did, but only shows a small image. The full width is not used.

```
WebView infoT = (WebView)rootView.findViewById( R.id.picture_show);
infoT.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8"); 
infoT.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
infoT.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls( true);
infoT.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<html><head><style>img{ -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); max-width: 100%; }</style></head><body><img src=\"file://" + pictureFile + "\"/></body></html>", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

The layout file of the fragment is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<WebView
   android:id="@+id/picture_show"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:scrollbars="vertical" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I also tried options like:

```
infoT.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body style =\"text-align:center\"><img style=\"border-style:dotted;border-width:5px;border-color:black;width:99%;-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);\" src=\"file://" + pictureFile + "\"/></body></html>","text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was not easy, but finally I found it. 
OK, this does exactly solve my question.

As a BONUS there is also a Html/Javascript button to rotate the image.

It consists of (1) the loadDataWithBaseUrl statement, (2) the string parts.

1. The load part:

   ```
   WebView infoT = (WebView)rootView.findViewById( R.id.picture_show);
   infoT.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8"); 
   infoT.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
   infoT.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
   infoT.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true);
   infoT.loadDataWithBaseURL( null, htmlTextPart1 + pictureFile + htmlTextPart2, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
   ```
2. The htmlTextPart1 and htmlTextPart2 strings are given below. For readability I give you only the HTML code parts. You can put them in strings.

   String htmlTextPart1 =

   ```
   <html>  
   <head>  
   <style>  
   #container {width:100%;overflow:hidden;}  
   #container.rotate90,#container.rotate270 {height:100%;}  
   #image {  
       transform-origin: top left;  
       -webkit-transform-origin: top left;  
       -ms-transform-origin: top left;  
       -moz-transform-origin: top left;  
       -o-transform-origin: top left;  
       max-width: 100%; width:100%; height: auto;  
       //  height: 1600 ... gives a large picture
   }  
   #container.rotate90 #image {  
      transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);  
      -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);  
      -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);  
      -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);  
      -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);  
       max-height: 100%; height:100%; width: auto;  
   }  
   #container.rotate180 #image {  
       transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-100%,-100%);  
       -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-100%,-100%);  
       -moz-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-100%,-100%);  
       -o-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-100%,-100%);  
       -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-100%,-100%);  
       max-width: 100%; width:100%; height: auto;  
   }  
   #container.rotate270 #image {  
       transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);  
       -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);  
       -moz-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);  
       -o-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);  
       -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);  
       max-height: 100%; height:100%; width: auto;  
   }  
   </style>  
   <script>  
   var angle = 0;  
   function rotateImageClockwise() {  
       img = document.getElementById('container');  
       angle = (angle+90)%360;  
       img.className = "rotate"+angle;  
   }  
   </script>  
   </head>
   <body>  
   <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Rotate image" onclick="javascript:rotateImageClockwise();" /></br>  
   <div id="container"><img src="file://"
   ```

   String part 2:

   ```
   id="image" /></div>
   </body>  
   </html>
   ```